# What are the advantages of using an errback?

Tags: javascript, callback

Programmers seem divided on how to get asynchronously notified about an error.

Some programmers prefer to use a callback with two arguments: a value and a boolean which tells whether the value isn't erroneous. This has the benefit in that it looks like a `try catch` statement:

```
asyncFunct(function (value, noError) {
    if (noError) {
        // success, do something with value
    } else {
        // value is the error which is thrown
    }
});
```

Others prefer the negative (i.e. the boolean should tell whether the value is erroneous). Their reasoning is that if you know that the asynchronous function will never throw an error then you can safely omit the second parameter as follows:

```
asyncFunction(function (value, isErroneous) {
    if (!isErrorneous) {
        // success, do something with value
    } else {
        // value is the error which is thrown
    }
});

asyncFunction(function (value) {
    // success, do something with value
});
```

Then there are people who propose separate callbacks for successful execution of asynchronous functions and errbacks for erroneous execution of asynchronous functions. This allows the programmer to select if he want to handle callbacks, errbacks, both or none:

```
asyncFunction(function (value) {
    // success, do something with value
}, function (error) {
    // handle the error
});

asyncFunction(function (value) {
    // success, do something with value
});

asyncFunction(null, function (error) {
    // handle the error
});
```

I'm not asking for which method you prefer. I'm simply asking for the advantages and disadvantages of each method so that I know which one to use when.

Comment: There are no real advantages/disadvantages. It is just a matter of style, imho.

Comment: There is another way, which is much more powerful IMO: [deferred objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx).

Comment: I prefer deferred objects too. But whatever method you choose use it consistently throughout your app, consistency is often more important than choosing the _best_ approach.

Comment: Yeah, deferred objects are brilliant - absolutely use them. But if you're writing an API, and don't want to require the use of deferreds, I'd say go the Node.js route: Single callback, 1st argument is the error or null. Then you can have X number of other arguments after that. And as msanders says, internal consistency is the most important thing, but if you can achieve external consistency too (e.g. using Node.js' patterns if you're writing something for Node) that's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Design Decision:**

This is just design decisions, nothing more. If it's standalone parameter, you can have standalone function and create "more beautiful" code (for someone - for someone it's more messy - it's really subjective).

**Error complexity:**

In some applications you can have more complex errors (`filesystem.fileRead` can have FILE_DONT_EXISTS, FILE_LOCKED, NOT_PERMISSIONS..) and in some apps you need just throw error (`db.checkConnection` or `db.openConnection`).

**Order and differences:**

Very nice sample for great API is from Amazon, you can check it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

**RESPONSE:** On asynch function like `copyObject(params = {}, callback)` you have callback function, which have always 2 parameters: `err (Error)` and `data (Object)` in `function(err, data) { ... }`. Error is designed like a first parameter because if you have error, you don't have a data. So it's really about priority and about order.

```
// request

getObject({
   param1 : something,
   param2 : something,
   param3 : something
}, callback);

// response

function callback(error, response){
   if error throw err;
   // now deal with responsei
}
```

**As you can see, you have both mixed two ways. In request you pass object and function and in response you get error and object (to that request function).**